misunderstand save action magefan blog
I have question on how do you guys save post_category relationship, when i debug save action, i just saw Post to be saved , how magic underneath the hood
https://github.com/magefan/module-blog


After saving the post, it calls the post model's _afterSave function, which updates the relationship data for categories and tags:
Model/ResourceModel/Post.php
    protected function _afterSave(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
    {
        ...

        /* Save category & tag links */
        foreach (['category' => 'categories', 'tag' => 'tags'] as $linkType => $dataKey) {
            $newIds = (array)$object->getData($dataKey);
            foreach ($newIds as $key => $id) {
                if (!$id) { // e.g.: zero
                    unset($newIds[$key]);
                }
            }
            if (is_array($newIds)) {
                $lookup = 'lookup' . ucfirst($linkType) . 'Ids';
                $oldIds = $this->$lookup($object->getId());
                $this->_updateLinks(
                    $object,
                    $newIds,
                    $oldIds,
                    'magefan_blog_post_' . $linkType,
                    $linkType . '_id'
                );
            }
        }


sure thank you <3
